# Angular Material dark theme not applying to text

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, angular-material

So I'm trying to implement a dark mode on the whole application. Up until now I made a service to catch a click event from the navigation component. The theme switches but text doesnt change its color.

Angular CLI: 15.2.9
Node: 16.17.0
Package Manager: npm 9.6.6
OS: win32 x64

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ThemeService {
  private isDarkModeSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  isDarkMode$ = this.isDarkModeSubject.asObservable();

  toggleTheme() {
    const currentMode = this.isDarkModeSubject.value;
    this.isDarkModeSubject.next(!currentMode);
  }

  isDarkMode() {
    return this.isDarkModeSubject.value;
  }
}
```

```
@use "@angular/material" as mat;

@import "@angular/material/theming";

// Defining Theme
@include mat.core();

$light-primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$purple-palette, 900, 800, 600);
$light-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$teal-palette, A200, A100, A400);

$dark-primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$green-palette, 900, 800, 600);
$dark-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$pink-palette, A200, A100, A400);

$general-warn: mat.define-palette(mat.$red-palette);

$light-theme: mat.define-light-theme(
  (
    color: (
      primary: $light-primary,
      accent: $light-accent,
      warn: $general-warn,
      text: (
        primary: yellow,
        secondary: red,
      ),
    ),
  )
);

@include mat.all-component-themes($light-theme);

$dark-theme: mat.define-dark-theme(
  (
    color: (
      primary: $dark-primary,
      accent: $dark-accent,
      warn: $general-warn,
      text: (
        primary: pink,
        secondary: green,
      ),
    ),
  )
);

.darkMode {
  @include mat.all-component-colors($dark-theme);
}

// Other Global Styles
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  //background-color: rgb(109, 167, 148);
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  background-color: rgb(163, 216, 181);
}

// Apply text colors to global styles
p {
  color: map-get(
    $light-theme,
    text,
    primary
  ); 
}

.darkMode {
  p {
    color: map-get(
      $dark-theme,
      text,
      primary
    ); 
  }
}
```

I'd be glad for any kind of help since I'm new to this.